# What happens to standalone DS-160?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, us-visa-waiver-program

I see a DS-160 requires a lot of time to complete. Can I submit a standalone DS-160 first (in case I might need one in the future)?

That is, can I do a DS-160 submission without any intention to schedule a follow-up B1-2 visa interview, because I belong to a VWP country?

Would doing so incur any prejudice if any?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to do? Submit the DS-160 so they process it, not schedule the interview, obviously not use the visa, and then months or years later, just schedule the interview? I don't think that works, you would probably need to restart the process from scratch beyond a few weeks/months as your situation may have changed a lot in between... Not sure what the cut-off is, though.

Comment: I don't know whether you can do this, but I can offer some remarks that might be of use: (1) being eligible for the VWP doesn't matter; (2) nationals of most VWP countries get a 10-year B visa by default; you can actually apply now for a visa without concrete plans to travel, though it might make your application less successful; (3) to travel to US on the VWP, you do not need to complete the DS-160, only ESTA, so there's not much point in doing this unless you know that you won't meet the VWP criteria, which isn't likely, especially in the absence of concrete plans.